# Is there ever any reason to branch/commit in a Git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to set up a Git repository with multiple components at the moment, and I'm a little confused about how/whether to use this.

The way I understand it, on a project, each component should have a master repository containing all the changes associated with that component. Then to produce a full image of software, we can set up a super-repository that points to a particular branch on the component master repository, and goes and gets the most recent commit when you update. This can all be handled by the .gitmodules configuration.

And, if we want to make updates to a component, surely we can always go back to the appropriate repo and push/pull...which seems much simpler (even if it takes more steps).

So, what is the use case for creating branches within the submodules? Is there such a use case? Why are we allowed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Branches have various uses. To list a few mostly used

1. An individual can use it to work on a specific bug
2. A set of engineers can use it to work on a common work item